# The target "PostBuildEvent" does not exist in the project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, post-build-event

My application had a post build event in it but I was removing due to some required changes resulting in the following error.

> The target "PostBuildEvent" does not exist in the project

So I went into my projects properties > Build Events to remove it.  However once removed I would still get the error while executing the application.  I then opened my `.csproj` to manually remove the post build event from there but that had the same result.  Am I not removing the post build event properly or is there some kind of error occurring here?  If there is an error what is a possible solution?

**Update:**

It doesn't seem to solely be a problem with any one application but all applications in Visual Studio, including new applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reinstallation of Visual Studio has successfully solved the problem.